# Howto write Azure logs from app hosted in container

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, logging, cloud

I have an app hosted in azure kubernetes with docker image in a container.

Kubernetes cluster insights Is showing logs on app error but there are not so many details about app error, is only showing something like error AND an small description.

I would like modify the log error message to show more details, could be this done by yarn file edit or something like that ???

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit your application to generate more meaningful logs.